# what this syntax for : and code do in java?

Tags: java, syntax

i never seen this before
can u explain me what is this??

```
for(Puzzle p:daughtersList)
.....
.....
```

Puzzle is a class and daughtersList is an arraylist

Comment: That is a [For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Comment: [Enhanced For Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Comment: It enumerates all Puzzle item in the daughtersList (like foreach in C#)

Comment: it helped me to understand this construct by reading it as such: "For each Puzzle p in daughtersList" where p is a temporary variable that each Puzzle will be called as you iterate through all of them

Answer (score 1):

This is the so-called ["for each" loop in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), which has been present since 1.5.

It loops over every element of the [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) or array on the right of the colon, with an implicit `Iterator`.

It is equivalent to the following code:

```
for (Iterator<Puzzle> i = daughtersList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Puzzle p = i.next();
    // .....
    // .....
}
```

Quoting from `Iterable` Javadocs linked above:

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the
>   "foreach" statement.

And lots of things in Java implement `Iterable`, including `Collection` and `Set`, and `ArrayList` is a `Collection` (and therefore an `Iterable`).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an alternative way to write a for-loop. It's called "for-each", because it goes through all the items in your list. An example would be that each "Puzzle" had a name accessible via a `getName()` method and you wanted to print the names of all the Puzzles in the list. You could then do this:

```
for(Puzzle p : daugthersList){        // For each Puzzle p, in the list daughtersList
    System.out.println(p.getName());  // Print the name of the puzzle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its called for-each loop

The right side of `:` must be an instance of `Iterable` (`daughtersList` is `ArrayList` which essentially implements `Iterable`) for this code to work

its a short form of

```
for(Iterator i = daughtersList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Puzzle p = (Puzzle) i.next();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(Puzzle p:daughtersList)` is a `foreach` loop. It iterate through all the element of daugterlist. in each iteration p holds the current element

it is a similar alternative of the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < daughterList.length(); i++ )
   // now use daughetList[i]
```